SVN delete folder from client
I've following project structure and two users, user1 and user2.
/code/proj1
/code/proj2

user1 works on both the projects but user2 works only on proj2. My Path-Based access configuration is as follows:
[/code/proj1]
user1=rw
user2=rw

[/code/proj2]
user1=
user2=rw

Now I want to revoke access for user1 to proj2 so user1 will work only on proj1 and user2 will work only on proj2. I changed the path based access config as follows.
[/code/proj1]
user1=rw
user2=

[/code/proj2]
user1=
user2=rw

The problem I see is, when user1 did svn update after I changed the config, proj1 is not deleted from user1's local machine.
My question is how can we force the client(for user1) to update itself and delete any directory/file for which the access is revoked? proj2 in this case.

Subversion is very careful to never modify or delete unversioned files.
Therefore, the only way to delete those files is to log into the client machine and delete them from there.
Even if it was possible to remotely delete files, it's not sure what purpose it should serve.
Your user1 could already have made local copies of proj2.
You can't travel back in time and change the past.
The fact that user1 can no longer commit changes and won't get updates on proj2 is really all you can hope to accomplish.
